# How to connect to an another server from apache mina server's MessageRecieved API

Tags: java, tcp, webserver, apache-mina

Im developing a simple TCP server with apache mina. Im able to recieve the message from my TCP client. Now i would like to simply route this message to my backend server which is running in an another machine i.e my mina server job is to simply route the message (outside firewall).

Its like

TCP Client <---> Apache Mina Server <---> Actual backend server

How can i connect to the backend server from my mina server's MessageRecieved() API.

Meaning,

1. Client sends the request.
2. On MessageRecived(), i need to send the inBuffer to backend server.
3. Backend server will return outBuffer.
4. Write the outbuffer to session.write() of server's MessageRecived API (point 2)

Answer (score 0):

As of my Knowledge you can use Remote Method Innocation(RMI,
i.e calling JDK API's(System,Date,Streams,additional jar apis) of one machine from another JDK installed machine.

Comment: Thanks. But im talking about apache mina!